# MySql Procedure GOTO Statement

Tags: mysql

I want to use goto statement in Mysql stored procedure in such manner that I execute my cursor whenever condition become true once again.

This is a sample code only, I just looking for goto statement

```
BLOCK_BACKLOG:begin
    declare backlgId, oldCOR, oldATR,oldCourse,oldATR,isFormFilled,nextParentId int;
    declare backlogNoMoreRow boolean default false;

Label : TestLineStart
    declare backlogCur cursor for select bcklg.id,cor.id,atr.id,cr.id,atr.obtainedMarks,atr.isFormFilled,atr.parentRegistration_id 
                from train bcklg,bus cor,fliet atr,fair co,distance cr 
                where bcklg.courseofferingregistration_id=cor.id and cor.academictermregistration_id=atr.id and cor.courseoffering_id=co.id and co.course_id=cr.id
                and bcklg.isDeleted is false and atr.id=parentId;
    declare continue handler for not found set backlogNoMoreRow=true;

    open backlogCur;

    LOOP_BACKLOG: loop
        fetch backlogCur into backlgId, oldCOR, oldATR,oldCourse,oldATRMarks,isFormFilled,nextParentId;                             

        if backlogNoMoreRow then
                close backlogCur;
                leave LOOP_BACKLOG;
        end if;

           if isFormFilled==0 then
        parentId=nextParentId;
        GOTO TestLineStart;
        end if;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134300/how-to-use-goto-label-in-mysql-stored-function

Comment: yes, may duplicated but i want to known that is it possible to execute courser one more time when condition becomes true. if goto not work in mysql then what is secondary way

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LOOP` on the outer block based on the value for variable `isFormFilled`.

Following change may help you.

```
-- Label : TestLineStart
TestLineStart: LOOP
-- other part of your SP as it is
```

and make following change:

```
if isFormFilled==0 then
    parentId=nextParentId;
    -- GOTO TestLineStart;
else
    leave TestLineStart;
end if;
```

You have to close all `loop` statements properly.