# How to use goto MSSQL in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am working on project where MS SQl project is migrating to Mysql.

In that goto statements are used in MSSQL, but i didnt find any goto control statements in Mysql.
There is lot of code written in goto labels in my MSSQL project, and also it is used depending on conditions.

Can i have any such syntax like goto in mysql?
How to write repeated code at once and call from anywhere in procedure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use goto label in MySQL stored function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134300/how-to-use-goto-label-in-mysql-stored-function)

Comment: Condolences. I understand wanting to go to open source or lower cost options, but MySql has lagged behind the other major DBs over the last decade. Sql Server, Oracle, and Postgresql are all much more capable these days, and Postgresql is also open source and low cost.

Comment: Goto...whether in SQL or C++, Java, or any OOP language is considered bad practice. Its essentially a case statement anyways. Please read [GoTo - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180188.aspx) on the subject to see why and how.