# How to stop execute full stored procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, control-flow

I have written a procedure in MySQL. I have set some conditions in my procedure. IF condition will not fill up then procedure will exit or full procedure will not execute. That means i want to stop to execute next lines of my procedure. In oracle i have used   **GOTO stop_level;**. In MySQL i have seen that my full procedure have been executed. I want to declare a LEAVE label so that it can jump to LEAVE label & return with set message. Here is my MySQL procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_spring.`login_auth`(IN  in_email      varchar(100),
                                    IN  in_password   varchar(100),                                       
                                    OUT user_id       INT,
                                    OUT out_code      INT,
                                    OUT out_message   VARCHAR(1024))
BEGIN
  BEGIN
   IF in_email IS NULL OR in_email = ''
    THEN
       SET out_code = 1;
       SET out_message = 'Please Enter Your Email.';
        /* Exit here*/
  END IF;

 IF in_password IS NULL OR in_password = ''
   THEN
     SET out_code = 1;
     SET out_message = 'Please Enter Your password.';
     /* Exit here*/
 END IF;


 END  ;


END;
```

I have used oracle **GOTO** function. When condition will not match then i call GOTO stop_label, it will jump to stop label not executing next line code. I want to handle my Procedure like oracle **GOTO stop_level** Here is **stop_level** code

```
  <<stop_level>>
 IF out_code = 0
 THEN
    COMMIT;
    out_message := out_message;
  ELSE
     ROLLBACK;
      out_code := 1;
      out_message := out_message;
  END IF;
```

How to do it?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, your question is what is similar to `GOTO` in MySQL. right ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use goto label in MySQL stored function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134300/how-to-use-goto-label-in-mysql-stored-function)

Comment: you are right. i want handle like this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have `GOTO` similar to Oracle, but they do have option to move control using **[`LEAVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/leave.html)** level (which you already mentioned). In your scenario, you could level your `BEGIN` block

```
leaveBlock:BEGIN
IF in_email IS NULL OR in_email = ''
    THEN
       SET out_code = 1;
       SET out_message = 'Please Enter Your Email.';
        LEAVE leaveBlock;
  END IF;

 IF in_password IS NULL OR in_password = ''
   THEN
     SET out_code = 1;
     SET out_message = 'Please Enter Your password.';
     LEAVE leaveBlock;
 END IF;

END leaveBlock;
```