# How to `ITERATE` in a `FOR` loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, stored-procedures, foreach, mariadb

```sql
person_loop: FOR person IN (
    SELECT id FROM person
) DO
    IF person.id MOD 2 = 0 THEN
        ITERATE person_loop;
    END IF;

    SELECT person.id;
END FOR person_loop;
```

This code doesn't work in MariaDB 10.4.24; I get the following error due to the use of `ITERATE`:

```
DB ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Is there any way to do the equivalent of calling `ITERATE` in a loop (e.g. `LOOP`, `WHILE`) in a `FOR` loop, or do I have to just resort to doing things the old, clunky way using cursors and `FETCH`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up employing [this strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071605):

```sql
FOR person IN (
    SELECT id FROM person
) DO
    loop_body: BEGIN
        IF person.id MOD 2 = 0 THEN
            LEAVE loop_body;
        END IF;

        SELECT person.id;
    END loop_body;
END FOR;
```